# How do I add h1 tag to $('a') in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is what displays at the final stage of a jquery quiz. It isn't formatting correctly on my site (maybe battling my CMS a little), but h1 tags are the format I want.

How do I make this also make the a href an h1 tag?

```
$('<a>')
.addClass('#subscribetext')
.attr('id','subscribetext')
.attr('href','https://www.hamsterdance.org/subscribe')
.html('')
.text('Sign me up!')
.insertAfter('#tweetresult');
```

Comment: Put it in your `html()`

Comment: You want to wrap the `a` tag or change it? If you change it to an `h1` the href is no longer a valid attribute.

Comment: You want to add `h1`  tag inside `a` tag or you want to change `a` tag to `h1` tag??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.append()` and not `.text()`

If you use `.text('<h1>Sign me up!</h1>')` it will display `<h1>Sign me up!</h1>`

 but if you use `.append('<h1>Sign me up!</h1>')` it will display

## Sign me up!

```
$('<a>')
.addClass('subscribetext')
.attr('id','subscribetext')
.attr('href','https://www.hamsterdance.org/subscribe')
.append('<h1>Sign me up!</h1>')
.insertAfter('#tweetresult');
```

**Demo**

```js
$('<a>')
.addClass('subscribetext')
.attr('id','subscribetext')
.attr('href','https://www.hamsterdance.org/subscribe')
.append('<h1>Sign me up!</h1>')
.insertAfter('#tweetresult');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tweetresult"></div>
```

Comment: It is still not a valid html since an `a` element is an inline element, which shouldn't include a block element like `h1`.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. It is valid in HTML 5

Comment: Thank you for teaching me! That worked perfectly @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap the link with another element like `h1`. You can also set the attributes on creating the element, which has better performance.

```
$('<a>', {
    id: 'subscribetext',
    'class': '#subscribetext',
    href: 'https://www.hamsterdance.org/subscribe'
  })
  .text('Sign me up!')
  .insertAfter('#tweetresult')
  .wrap('<h1></h1>');
```